# External hard drive won't mount or show up

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, external-disk

I have tried all sorts of things but still won't mount and I have no idea what to do, I used the ps aux | grep fsck command but no result.

I'd be grateful for any help. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem not so long ago - the disk was originally formatted on a really old OSX machine - and wouldn't show up on the recent machine ...  In the end after a few reboots, and trying on a few other machines I swapped cables and it came good ..

Comment: What happens if you run `diskutil mountDisk disk4`? Do you care about the data on the disk or are happy to erase it?